# Can't change the material map of one particle in three.js

Tags: three.js

I've created a lot of particles using THREE.Particle(). My particles are stars.

I want only one of them to animate slightly, just like a star.

I'm trying to do:

`var oneParticle = scene.children[ Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 + 1))];
oneParticle.material.map = generateSprite();`

generateSprite() is a function that returns valid canvas.

The problem is that generateSprite() is being applied to every particle, not the only one.

I realised that i have to use another material to make it happen, but it means i should to create a material for each animated star and it's not cool.

I'm new to three.js and i assume, that there must be simple, kind way to change only one particle's texture with an animation, but can't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use another particlesystem (and thus, another material) for the one unique star. I don't think you can have multiple. This way the other particles are still rendered efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised how to fix my problem by myself. Will leave it here in case of need.

First of all, i'm creating material for particle "runtime":

```
while(particleCount--) {
    var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({ 
        map: new THREE.Texture( generateSprite() ), 
    });

    var particle = new THREE.Particle( material );
}
```

generateSprite() returns me a canvas. Yes, i understand, that it decreases performance, but in my case i have 500 particles. It's not too much, i suppose.

I wrote function, that grabs random particle and changes it's context:

```
function transformParticle() {
    var oneParticle = scene.children[ Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 + 1))];
    var ctx = oneParticle.material.map.image.getContext('2d');

    // ctx change code here
};
```

And then i just call this function in requestAnimationFrame and it works - changing only one particle's texture without creating unique materials etc.

And i think, that using .getChildByName could be a better idea, but can't find any proof.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer if it solves your original question!